# How to set xaml binding properly

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, binding, windows-phone

```
<TextBlock x:Name="PageTitle" Text="{Binding tripTypeViewModel.test}"/>
```

This is my XAML binding to a property in my ViewModel test. How to make the binding not specifying the ViewModel object 'tripTypeViewModel' since I will need to change the data context in runtime programmatically, so it wont be always this?

Heres the full scenario:

```
class CompositeViewModel
{
    public static TripsResponseTypeViewModel tripsResponseTypeViewModel { get; set; }
    public static TripTypeViewModel          tripTypeViewModel          { get; set; }

    static CompositeViewModel()
    {
        tripsResponseTypeViewModel = new TripsResponseTypeViewModel();
        tripTypeViewModel          = new TripTypeViewModel();
    }
}
```

In my Page.xaml I set the Data Context like this:

```
public MyTripsPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    this.DataContext = new CompositeViewModel();
}
```

So sometimes I want to change the ItemsSource property of ListBoxes on tripTypeViewModel collections or others.. That is why i need a master class like CompositeViewModel, but how to prevent the XAML specific binding?

Comment: You don't need to specifiy that. If `test` is a property on your viewModel defined as a DataContext of `PageTitle` then `{Binding test}` would suffice

Comment: I though so, but it doesnt. It works only when I specify the VM object.. Actually the DataContext of my Page is set to a MasterClass that contains 2 other ViewModel objects, one of which is tripTypeViewModel

Comment: Are you sure `tripTypeViewModel` is infact your `DataContext` and not maybe a property on your DataContext? Post the code where you set the `DataContext` ...

Comment: That is the situation. How can i fix it, because I will need to change my ItemsSource of some elements in the page to the properties in my ViewModel Master class dinamically.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a common interface for all the possible `DataContext`'s and bind it to your `PageTitle`

```
    public class CompositeViewModel
    {
        public ITest SelectedViewModel { get; set; }

        // Init the VM's and change them at run time ...
    }

    public class TripsResponseTypeViewModel : ITest
    {
        public string test { get; set; }
    }

    public class TripTypeViewModel : ITest
    {
        public string test { get; set; }
    }

    public interface ITest
    {
        string test { get; set; } 
    }
```

In xaml

This way you make sure that no matter what `DataContext` `PageTitle` uses it will always have a `test` property which you can bind to using XAML